# evaluating this expression with 3 variables .

Tags: permutations, combinations

I was solving a problem and I am stuck with this expression. As I am not a mathematics guy can someone please help me out with this :

\begin{equation*}
\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=i}\sum^{n}_{k=j} a^i\ast (a^i-1)\ast (a^{j-i})\ast ((a^i-1)\ast (a^{j-i})-1)\ast a^{k-j}\ast mult.
\end{equation*}

where mult is a multipiler if i,j,k are same it is 1 if three of them are diffrent it is 6 and else it is 3.

How can this expression be reduced and simplified? Please help. Thanks in advance. I think it is something permutations and combination stuff.

Comment: Well $a^ia^{j-i}a^{k-j}=a^k$  That's a start

Comment: $$(a)^i(a^i-1)(a^{j-i})((a^i-1)(a^{j-i})-1)(a^{k-j})=$$
$$a^k(a^i-1)((a^i-1)a^{j-i}-1)$$

So we get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}(a)^i(a^i-1)(a^{j-i})((a^i-1)(a^{j-i})-1)(a^{k-j})=$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}a^k(a^i-1)((a^i-1)a^{j-i}-1)=$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}-\frac{a^{-i}(a^i-1)(a^{i+j}-a^j-a^i)(a^j-a^{n+1})}{a-1}$$

Comment: @GregoryGrant i just missed out something in the question can you help it out a bit . thankyou

Comment: @JanEerland i just missed out something . cant this be more simplified ?

Comment: I am looking for it

Comment: @JanEerland can you guide me throgh it or any identities or formulaes which can be used over here ?

Comment: @user3520502 give me your email adres and I'll

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=i}\sum^{n}_{k=j} a^i\ast (a^i-1)\ast (a^{j-i})\ast ((a^i-1)\ast (a^{j-i})-1)\ast a^{k-j}=$$

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{j=i}\sum^{n}_{k=j} a^k(a^i-1)(a^{j-i}(a^i-1)-1)=$$

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a^i-1)\left(\sum_{j=i}^{n}(a^{n+1}-a^j)(a^{j-i}(a^i-1)-1)\right)}{a-1}=$$

$$\frac{\left(\frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1}-n\right)\left(\sum_{j=i}^{n}(a^{n+1}-a^j)(a^{j-i}(a^i-1)-1)\right)}{a-1}=$$

$$\frac{\left(\frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1}-n\right)\left(sum\right)}{a-1}$$

$$sum=\frac{1}{1-a^2}*a^{-i}\left((i-n-3)a^{i+n+1}-2a^{i+n+2}+(-i+n+1)a^{i+n+3}+a^{2i+n+1}+a^{2b+i+2}-a^{i+2n+3}+2a^{2i}-2a^{3i}+a^{2i+1}+a^{2n+3}\right)$$

Comment: wooh it is quite long and i had tried even and it is really long an tedious task . thanks for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome, buddy!

Comment: i had derived it in terms of n and k but somehow not giving correct result :\